# ST_Transform is way too inexact

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I have a Point

```
RW     HW     EPSG
3011.65;341146.38;31256
```

which ST_Transform transforms into projection
EPSG=4326, Lat;Lon
48.2086988651298;16.3686458354975

However, when using http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/ and checking with Google Maps and openstreetmap, the actual result should be
48.2087130847;16.3726546685;

This is much to inaccurate.

Am I doing sthg wrong when using Transform?

EDIT1: That's the way I use it:

```
select ST_Y(a.b), ST_X(a.b) from
  (select ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(3011.65, 341146.38), 31256), 4326) as b) as a
```

Comment: Please include the statement you are using to pass the point to ST_Transform()

Comment: @kttii updated the questions with selectable example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like PostGIS is performing some geographic/datum transformation because the output values aren't just the MGI Austria values unprojected into MGI latitude-longitude values (48.209213766 16.37385929).

I checked EPSG::1618 and EPSG::5891 but neither matched exactly. what you're getting from the mygeodata website. EPSG::1618, MGI to WGS 1984 (3) gave closer results. The EPSG::5891 transformation uses the NTv2 grid, AT_GIS.gsb.

It's possible the underlying PROJ.4 version doesn't have the NTv2 grid file (and the mygeodata doesn't either) or that the PROJ.4 definitions associated with MGI-based PCS haven't been updated to use one of the more recent transformations.

There's some information about it in the [ST_Transform](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) documentation.

Comment: When I perform the translation on the mygeodata - site it uses this paramters for Proj.4:, SRID=31256: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=16.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs whereas PostGIS has stored "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=16.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +datum=hermannskogel +units=m +no_defs " in column proj4text.

Comment: That's epsg::1618.

Answer (score 3):

You are using ST_Makepoint which is expecting Lat Long values.  To convert your 31256 SRID point to 4326 SRID you need to use ST_Point, set the SRID with ST_SetSRID and then transform it with ST_Transform in PostGIS 2.2.2:

```
SELECT ST_y(a.b) , st_x(a.b)
FROM (
    SELECT ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(3011.65,341146.38),31256),4326) as b) as a
```

and the result is:

> 48.20871308466652 16.372654668537162

and my values for SRID 4326 and 31256 are:

```
    srid    auth_name   auth_srid   srtext  proj4text
    4326    EPSG    4326    GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]    
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
    31256   EPSG    31256   PROJCS["MGI / Austria GK East",GEOGCS["MGI",DATUM["Militar_Geographische_Institute",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],TOWGS84[577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6312"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4312"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",16.33333333333333],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",-5000000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","31256"]]   
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=16.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +datum=hermannskogel +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: That's strange, your select seems to give the correct answer while mine doesn't. `SELECT PostGIS_full_version();` gives "POSTGIS="2.2.2 r14797" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11.99" (core procs from "2.2.1 r14555" need upgrade) RASTER (raster procs from "2.2.1 r14555" need upgrad (...)"

Comment: use ST_Point the way I am for now rather than ST_MakePoint

Comment: Tried that, it delivers the same (~wrong) result

Comment: updated answer... ST_MakePoint() is expecting Lat/Long

Comment: @JohnDoe Updated my select statement to use your values

Comment: Unfortunatelly that does not change my results at all. It seems like my  PostGIS - Version uses old / outdated projection defintions, cf. answer @mkennedy

Comment: @JohnDoe I included my values for: select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=31256 or srid=4326

Comment: @mkennedy  I compared your output from the above select with mine and they are the same. I really have no more clue what's going on here

Comment: @JohnDoe To clarify, you have the same values that I have for SRID but you are still getting the wrong result?

Comment: I got the same issue between two versions of PostGIS, but with DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 3 projection https://epsg.io/31467, which is also Transverse Mercator. What I found is that projection code for it was rewritten at some point, but they supposedly kept backward compatibility via +approx options in proj4 definition (it didn't work for me) https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/404

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I did was:

First:

`DELETE FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE auth_srid = 31256;`

Then (According to http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/mgi-austria-gk-east/postgis/):

`INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 31256, 'EPSG', 31256, '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=16.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs ', 'PROJCS["MGI / Austria GK East",GEOGCS["MGI",DATUM["Militar_Geographische_Institute",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],TOWGS84[577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6312"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4312"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",16.33333333333333],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",-5000000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","31256"]]');`